# How to record a video and make it slow motion

Tags: iphone, ios4, video-capture

I am working on an iPhone app for school and need some help. The app should record video, make it slow motion (about 2x), then save it to the photo library. So far I have everything except how to make the video slow motion. I know it can be done as there is already an app in the App Store that does it.

How can I take a video I've saved to a temp url and adjust the speed before saving it to the photo library?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296999/how-to-do-slow-motion-video-in-ios/33914602#33914602 ...check this link this might help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to export your video then you need to use the [AVMutableComposition Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableComposition_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Then add your video as an  `AVAsset` to an `AVMutableComposition` and scale it with:

```
- (void)scaleTimeRange:(CMTimeRange)timeRange toDuration:(CMTime)duration
```

Finally you export it using [AVAssetExportSession Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I'm confused on how this can be used to make the video slow motion?

Answer (score 0):

I written a code that makes your video in "slow motion" and saves it in Photos Library. "Main Thing This Code Works In Swift 5". Creating "Slow motion" video in iOS swift is not easy, that I came across many "slow motion" that came to know not working or some of the codes in them are depreciated. And so I finally figured a way to make slow motion in Swift.
This code can be used for 120fps are greater than that too. Just add the url of your video and make it slow

Here is the "code snippet I created for achieving slow motion"

```
        func slowMotion(pathUrl: URL) {

    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset.init(url: pathUrl, options: nil)
    let currentAsset = AVAsset.init(url: pathUrl)

    let vdoTrack = currentAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

    let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    let videoInsertError: Error? = nil
    var videoInsertResult = false
    do {
        try compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(
            CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: videoAsset.duration),
            of: videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0],
            at: .zero)
        videoInsertResult = true
    } catch let videoInsertError {
    }

    if !videoInsertResult || videoInsertError != nil {
        //handle error
        return
    }


    var duration: CMTime = .zero
    duration = CMTimeAdd(duration, currentAsset.duration)
    
    
    //MARK: You see this constant (videoScaleFactor) this helps in achieving the slow motion that you wanted. This increases the time scale of the video that makes slow motion
    // just increase the videoScaleFactor value in order to play video in higher frames rates(more slowly)
    let videoScaleFactor = 2.0
    let videoDuration = videoAsset.duration
    
    compositionVideoTrack?.scaleTimeRange(
        CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: videoDuration),
        toDuration: CMTimeMake(value: videoDuration.value * Int64(videoScaleFactor), timescale: videoDuration.timescale))
    compositionVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = vdoTrack.preferredTransform
    
    let dirPaths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).map(\.path)
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
    let outputFilePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: docsDir).appendingPathComponent("slowMotion\(UUID().uuidString).mp4").path
    
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outputFilePath) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: outputFilePath)
        } catch {
        }
    }
    let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: outputFilePath)
    
    let assetExport = AVAssetExportSession(
        asset: mixComposition,
        presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    assetExport?.outputURL = filePath
    assetExport?.outputFileType = .mp4
    
    assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        switch assetExport?.status {
        case .failed:
            print("asset output media url = \(String(describing: assetExport?.outputURL))")
            print("Export session faiied with error: \(String(describing: assetExport?.error))")
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                // completion(nil);
            })
        case .completed:
            print("Successful")
            let outputURL = assetExport!.outputURL
            print("url path = \(String(describing: outputURL))")
            
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputURL!)
            }) { saved, error in
                if saved {
                    print("video successfully saved in photos gallery view video in photos gallery")
                }
                if (error != nil) {
                    print("error in saing video \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                //      completion(_filePath);
            })
        case .none:
            break
        case .unknown:
            break
        case .waiting:
            break
        case .exporting:
            break
        case .cancelled:
            break
        case .some(_):
            break
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[slowmoVideo](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/index.html) is an OSS project which appears to do this very nicely, though I don't know that it would work on an iPhone.

> It does not simply make your videos play at 0.01× speed. You can
>   smoothly slow down and speed up your footage, optionally with motion
>   blur. How does slow motion work? slowmoVideo tries to find out where
>   pixels move in the video (this information is called Optical Flow),
>   and then uses this information to calculate the additional frames.