# How to ramp the Audio using Avfoundation?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

Ramp the Video using AVfoundation - scaleTime Range is working as per the below code :

```
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    BOOL videoInsertResult = [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, trimmedDuration) ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:insertionPoint error:nil];
    [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:sourceVideoTrack.preferredTransform];
    [compositionVideoTrack scaleTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(inTime, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(startTime,5)) toDuration:CMTimeMake(outTime.value*1.0, outTime.timescale)];
```

How to ramp the Audio using AVFoundation ?

I Used the Dirac API to slow down the audio. It doesn't help much. Can you suggest any other api's ? or How to Ramp using objective-c ?

I want to play the Video and audio from slow to Fast (Ramp) ?

Comment: need to take a look at this hope it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296999/how-to-do-slow-motion-video-in-ios/17500970#17500970

Comment: yes this one is posted by me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296999/how-to-do-slow-motion-video-in-ios/17500970#17500970 . I couldn't get the ramp for Audio in that case. . Can you please advice any idea for ramp the audio using scaletimeRange ?