# Swift - Slow Motion Camera in App

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera

I'm been learning Swift and iOS development and am interested in making an application that uses the camera on the back of the iPhone to shoot slow motion video and then allow the user to use a slider to move through the video normally, but also to move frame by frame. Of course, this would be regulated by a button that transitioned the user from "normal navigation" to frame by frame. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Are there any resources where I can read about using the "slo-mo" feature in a custom app? Thanks.

Comment: Note that the ability to take a decent slow-mo video will depend on the capture rate of the camera.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the user to be able to save the slow-mo video, what you could do is take a video shot, then have the app play it back in slow-mo. You can do all this using the AVFoundation framework. Here are some links to help you out:

[Taking Control of the iPhone Camera in iOS 8](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/taking-control-of-the-iphone-camera-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-1/)

[Objective-C: How to do slow-motion video in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296999/how-to-do-slow-motion-video-in-ios) (yes, this is for Objective-C, but you can change the code to Swift or just copy and paste it into a new Objective-C file)

Comment: Is it possible for me to have the user go frame by frame and choose certain frames? Are there numbered references to each frame that I could access? For instance, if the user is going frame by frame and chooses frame 100 of the video and frame 150of the video, is there a way I can get this information?