# Accelerate video speed to 10x

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, video-processing

Actually want to convert my captured video to 10 speed(means 10 time faster then original).

```
[compositionVideoTrack1 scaleTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoDuration)
                               toDuration:CMTimeMake(videoDuration.value*videoScaleFactor, videoDuration.timescale)];
```

its work fine but when i play this video in MPMoviePlayer its freeze the player, may be it's because of high frame rate i think.

Got the this link [Drop Frame Timecode and the NTSC Frame Rate](https://documentation.apple.com/en/finalcutpro/usermanual/index.html#chapter=D%26section=6%26tasks=true)

Please help me to find the proper solution, thanks ...

Comment: please refer [this Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296999/how-to-do-slow-motion-video-in-ios) post for accelerating video speed. It might be helpful.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara Thanks ,but i am using AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality for AVAssetExportSession so, while play in Movie player it freezes the player ,and if i use presetName:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality its working fine ,can you help me to know the issue where i am doing wrong ? thanks again..