# AVMutableCompositionTrack scaleTimeRange in IOS9.1 won't work for when creating a fast forward video

Tags: objective-c, video-processing, timelapse

I am using ScaleTimeRange method to create slow motion and fast video in IOS. 
It works perfectly fine in IOS 8 but not in 9.1 any more. 
It seems to me Apple just fucked it up and changed some stuffs. 
Here is my codes

```
double currentRecordingRate = [[recordingSpeedRateArray objectAtIndex: i] doubleValue];

    [currentTrack scaleTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(duration, currentAsset.duration)
                        toDuration:CMTimeMake( currentAsset.duration.value*currentRecordingRate,  currentAsset.duration.timescale)];
```

if currentRecordingRate is larger than 1, it will work fine (creating a slow motion video)
However if it's lower than 1, I just can't get a final video at all. It keep giving me error. 
Does anyone experience this kind of problem in IOS 9.1 when you are trying to do slow motion and fast forward video?

I am using the example codes from this example:
[How to do Slow Motion video in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296999/how-to-do-slow-motion-video-in-ios/33914602#33914602)